# zoom animation adjustment to adjacent items

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am doing a zoom animation in a infinite loop.
Each item is zoomed / scaled around 2.5x.

When zooming its overlapping with other adjacent items
How I can make it so current zooming item get enough space to zoom without any overlap.

Hope I am able to explain.

Thanks,
BT

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  10% { /* (100%/5)/2 */
    /*transform: translateY(-20px);*/
    transform: scale(2.50, 2.50);
    /*flex-grow: 4.3;*/
  }
  20% { /* (100%/5) */
    transform: translateY(0);
    flex-grow: clear;
  }
}
.main-box {
  width: 920px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
  border: solid yellow;
}
.box {
  width: 120px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: var(--bg);
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: bounce 16s var(--delay) infinite cubic-bezier(.2, .65, .6, 1);
}
.box.one {
  --bg: slateblue;
  --delay:calc(0*16s/5)
}
.box.two {
  --bg: deeppink;
  --delay:calc(1*16s/5)
}
.box.three {
  --bg: dodgerblue;
  --delay:calc(2*16s/5)
}
.box.four {
  --bg: red;
  --delay:calc(3*16s/5)
}
.box.five {
  --bg: yellow;
  --delay:calc(4*16s/5)
}


body {
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
  <div class="box one"></div>
  <div class="box two"></div>
  <div class="box three"></div>
  <div class="box four"></div>
  <div class="box five"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you set the width of the box to 80px using ```.box { width: 80px }```, the boxes in your example won't overlap. However, I suspect that's not what you're aiming for. Could you please clarify or provide an image to help us better understand your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you animate `width` instead of scaling the elements with `transform` they will not overlap, but rather "push" each other to make room:

```css
body {
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
}

.main-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border: solid yellow;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: var(--bg);
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: bounce 16s var(--delay) infinite cubic-bezier(.2, .65, .6, 1);
}

.box.one {
  --bg: slateblue;
  --delay: calc(0*16s/5)
}

.box.two {
  --bg: deeppink;
  --delay: calc(1*16s/5)
}

.box.three {
  --bg: dodgerblue;
  --delay: calc(2*16s/5)
}

.box.four {
  --bg: red;
  --delay: calc(3*16s/5)
}

.box.five {
  --bg: yellow;
  --delay: calc(4*16s/5)
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    width: 50px;
  }
  10% {
    width: 100px;
  }
  20% {
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
  <div class="box one"></div>
  <div class="box two"></div>
  <div class="box three"></div>
  <div class="box four"></div>
  <div class="box five"></div>
</div>
```